# Unity prefab instance doesn't save variable setting on PlayMode

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor, prefab

I have a `Сharacter` class with a `PositionOnGrid` property that stores the `Cell` component

```
public class Character
{
    public Cell PositionOnGrid;
}
```

`Сharacter` - it's just capsule mesh saved like prefab, i have this prefab instance on the scene.
`Cell` - the same with hexagonal mesh. Saved like prefab, i have many of this on the scene.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruZvf.jpg)

I'm trying to create a tool for conveniently placing objects on a grid in the Editor. Therefore, there is another script on the `Character` object that updates the `PositionOnGrid` and snap `transform.position` when I move the object on the stage.

```
[ExecuteAlways]
public class CharacterEditorMode : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Character _selfCharacter;

    private Raycaster _raycaster;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _selfCharacter = this.GetComponent<Character>();
        _raycaster = new Raycaster();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Application.isPlaying)
            return;

        if (transform.hasChanged)
        {
            UpdateCoordinates();
            transform.hasChanged = false;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCoordinates()
    {
        if (_raycaster.CastRayDownOnCellLayer(_selfCharacter.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0)))
        {
            GameObject cellObject = _raycaster.GetRayHitObject();
            Cell cellComponent = cellObject.GetComponent<Cell>();

            _selfCharacter.transform.position = cellObject.transform.position;
            _selfCharacter.PositionOnGrid = cellComponent;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it works in the editor, but when I run `PlayMode`, the prefab settings such as `PositionOnGrid` are reset to the default values from the prefab.([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5JPw.jpg))

They are marked in bold as edited, but I cannot apply the changes to the prefab, since I need  many instances with different settings.

I tried `PrefabUtility.RecordPrefabInstancePropertyModifications` |
`Undo.RecordObject` |
`EditorUtility.SetDirty` |
`[SerializeField]` tag

This did not give the desired result. Maybe I'm using these things wrong? By the way, prefab settings are saved on the stage even when the project is restarted. The problem occurs exactly when starting `PlayMode`.

If I remove the `Application.isPlaying` in `Update()` it seems to work. But this interferes with other methods for moving a character already within the game. This should only work in the editor.

```
if (Application.isPlaying)
    return;
```

If I set properties manually with hands, for example `Cell`, it is saved in `PlayMod`